# Reading txt file with floats into a 2-D Matrix

Tags: c, loops, pointers, matrix, floating-point

I'm trying to read "chol.txt" file with contents:

```
6 3 4 8
3 6 5 1
4 5 10 7
8 1 7 25
```

using the function: (where *ROW and *COL both have the value 4)

```
void ReadFile(float*** MATRIX, int* ROW, int* COL)
{
FILE* openF;

openF = fopen("chol.txt", "r");

for (int incROW = 0; incROW < *ROW; incROW++)
{
    for (int incCOL = 0; incCOL < *COL; incCOL++)
    {
        fscanf(openF, "%f", MATRIX[incROW][incCOL]);
        printf("MATRIX[%d][%d] has value %f\n", incROW, incCOL, (*MATRIX)[incROW][incCOL]);
    }
}

fclose(openF);
}
```

but it returns the text before crashing:

```
MATRIX[0][0] has value 6.000000
MATRIX[0][1] has value 0.000000
MATRIX[0][2] has value 4413697645709019316224.000000
MATRIX[0][3] has value 17751098170076127766626959360.000000
```

I can manually enter floats into the Matrix, but wanted to read from txt file now. Here is summary of my main():

```
void ReadFile(float*** MATRIX, int* ROW, int* COL);

int main()
{
int SIZE = 4;
float** M = NULL;

MakeNullMATRIX(&M, &SIZE, &SIZE);

ReadFile(&M, &SIZE, &SIZE);

return 0;
}
```

As requested MakeNullMATRIX:

```
void MakeNullMATRIX(float*** MATRIX, int* ROW, int* COL)
{
*MATRIX = (float **)malloc(*ROW * sizeof(float*));

for (int i = 0; i < *ROW; i++)
{
    (*MATRIX)[i] = (float *)malloc(*COL * sizeof(float));
}
}
```

Comment: That your question title says this is a 2x2 matrix, yet your sample data indicates this is a 4x4 matrix is only slightly concerning. That you're passing a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer-to-float even more so. Post your `main()` that invokes this.

Comment: And also `MakeNullMATRIX()`.

Comment: I found the solution  'fscanf(openF, "%f", **&(*MATRIX)**[incROW][incCOL]);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `fscanf()` should be like

```
fscanf(openF, " %f", &((*MATRIX)[incROW][incCOL]));
```

Comment: Thanks. It seemed redundant to me, but I finally thought it was worth a try and it worked!

Comment: @user3339814 `MATRIX[incROW][incCOL]` means you try to use `MATRIX` as a 2d array, but in your case `MATRIX` actually is a pointer to a 2d array.

Answer (score 1):

Well, sorry, but this looks way too complicated than required...

Anyway, without offering too many changes; while it's required for you to pass the address of `M` to the `MakeNullMATRIX`, you don't have to do so for `ReadFile`. So...

**1:** Changing this line:

```
ReadFile(&M, &SIZE, &SIZE);
```

like this:

```
ReadFile(M, ... );  // removed &
```

**2:** Then this line:

```
void ReadFile(float*** MATRIX, int* ROW, int* COL);
```

into this:

```
void ReadFile(float ** MATRIX, ... );  // removed one *
```

**3:** And then these lines:

```
fscanf(openF, "%f", MATRIX[incROW][incCOL]);
...
printf("MATRIX[%d][%d] has value %f\n", incROW, incCOL, (*MATRIX)[incROW][incCOL]);
```

into these:

```
fscanf( ... , &( MATRIX[incROW][incCOL]) );  // enclosed it with &( )
...
printf( ... , MATRIX[incROW][incCOL] );  // removed (* )
```

Should make it work as you'd like it to work, as well as making your code somewhat more friendly to a random reader.

But I seriously cannot understand why not a simple one like this:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void ReadFile( float * MATRIX, int * ROW, int * COL )
{
    FILE * openF = fopen( "chol.txt", "r" );

    if ( !openF ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "chol.txt is missing\n" );
        return;
    }

    for ( int incROW = 0; incROW < *ROW; incROW++ )
    {
        for ( int incCOL = 0; incCOL < *COL; incCOL++ )
        {
            fscanf( openF, "%f", MATRIX + (*ROW) * incROW + incCOL );
            printf( "MATRIX[%d][%d] has value %f\n", incROW, incCOL, *( MATRIX + (*ROW) * incROW + incCOL ) );
        }
    }

    fclose( openF );
}

int main( )
{
    int SIZE = 4;
    float * M = malloc( SIZE * SIZE * sizeof( *M ) );

    ReadFile( M, &SIZE, &SIZE );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm handling a few matrices at a time, so I tried to make it as modular and consistent as possible. Additionally, I'm going to perform a numerical decomposition of somewhat large matrices. I had a very strong feeling the problem was in the ReadFile(...) function rather than main() or MakeNullMATRIX(...) which is why I didn't include them until asked to; and what I did include was barebones.